# Determine if DLL_PROCESS_DETACH is last one

Tags: c++, dll

I'm working on a dll with UI components, and according to MSDN documentation we need to explicitly unregister window classes registered in the dll. (unlike when registering inside non dll process where the system unregisters them automatically)

Now the problem is that in the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` message in `DllMain` function we can tell when process unloads the dll or if it terminates, but how to determine if dll is about to be completly unloaded from memory?

because unregistering window classes on every process detach is not the right time since other windows might still use the registered class.

I want to unregister all classes once no other process is "using" the dll. that seems like correct time to do this.

Here is how I unregister all the classes at the moment:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    [[maybe_unused]] LPVOID lpReserved) noexcept
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        /*
        * Note As it turns out, HMODULEs and HINSTANCEs are exactly the same thing. 
        * If the documentation for a function indicates that an HMODULE is required, you can pass an HINSTANCE and vice versa.
        * There are two data types because in 16-bit Windows HMODULEs and HINSTANCEs identified different things
        */

        // static method call to Unregister all window classes
        wsl::ui::ClassAtoms::UnregisterClassAtoms(hModule);
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Here is implementation, if you are curious but it's not relevant.

```
namespace wsl::ui
{
    class ClassAtoms
    {
    public:
        static void AddClassAtom(const ATOM& atom)
        {
            mAtoms.push_back(atom);
        }

        static void UnregisterClassAtom(const ATOM& atom, const HINSTANCE& hInstance)
        {
            // If the class could not be found or if a window still exists
            // that was created with the class, the return value is zero.
            if (!UnregisterClass(MAKEINTATOM(atom), hInstance))
            {
                ShowError(ERR_BOILER);
            }
        }

        static void UnregisterClassAtoms(const HINSTANCE& hInstance)
        {
            for (auto& ref : mAtoms)
            {
                UnregisterClassAtom(ref, hInstance);
            }

            mAtoms.clear();
        }

    private:
        inline static std::vector<ATOM> mAtoms = {};

        // deleted
        ClassAtoms() = delete;
        ~ClassAtoms() = delete;
        ClassAtoms(const ClassAtoms&) = delete;
        ClassAtoms(ClassAtoms&&) = delete;
        ClassAtoms& operator=(const ClassAtoms&) = delete;
        ClassAtoms& operator=(ClassAtoms&&) = delete;
    };
}
```

Comment: Each process has its own dll loaded.. Why do you need to unload classes when all processes are terminated? You could use a mutex or semaphore.. Use a semaphore with count. When it reaches 0, signal and unregister but I can't see why you need this. Just have the class keep a reference count or use a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter.. when it has no more references, it will clean up.

Comment: Also, since you have a vector.. why don't you check when it's empty? Each class adds itself to it and in the destructor removes itself.. when it hits zero, call unregister?

Comment: @Brandon `Each process has its own dll loaded` i don't understand, isn't purpose of a dll to be shared among processes? I need to unregister to fulfill MSDN documentation. thank you for advice on semaphore, I think adding and static counter for each process attach inside dllmain could solve the issue.

Comment: Ok.. For example, I have a dll named "metablaster.dll".. I run program/process "A.exe" and it loads "metablaster.dll".. then I run program/process "B.exe" and it also loads "metablaster.dll".. B will NEVER know whether A has loaded it or not because it doesn't care. DLL instances are not shared amongst processes. They are literally mapped into each process's virtual address space. Each process gets its own instance of your dll.

Comment: Imagine if I had a dll and calling a function in one process somehow affected calling a function in another process, your entire OS would have so many problems as Windows itself also uses dlls.. If metablaster.dll crashed in one process, it should NOT affect another process. Therefore the windows in your first process have nothing to do with the windows in your second process and so on. Just free it in `DETACH` no matter what because the dll is unloaded and any threads or handles still alive are the result of a design problem.

Comment: I'll have to take a read somewhere about what you said, thank you for information. so do you think adding a static counter inside a dllmain will be unique among all loaded dll instances? or would static counter be local to each dll instance?

Comment: @Brandon I register classes with `CS_GLOBALCLASS` style flag, which makes them global to all processes not local to single process btw..

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060920-07/?p=29663 `"Don’t be the one responsible for having to issue a hotfix for your product. Unregister your classes if the process is going to continue running after your DLL unloads. Because it’s the right thing to do."`